# `XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String)` and `XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime)` outputs are inconsistent

Tags: c#, .net, xml, timezone

I having issues with `XmlConvert` and `DateTime`.

When converting some string with `XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String)` then convert resulted `DateTime` back to string with `XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime)` and resulting string is **different from the original string**, and depending on local TimeZone.

The following console application code demonstrating the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace DateTimeXmlConvertTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Original Value\t\t\t\tNew Value");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------\t\t\t\t---------");

            for (int i = -12; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                string sign = i < 0 ? "" : "+";

                string originalString = "2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000" + sign + i.ToString("D2") + ":00";
                DateTime now = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(originalString);
                string newValue = XmlConvert.ToString(now);
                Console.WriteLine(originalString + "\t" + newValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running this program on my PC (Windows 7 x64, TimeZone UTC+02:00 with Daylight) i have the following output:

```
Original Value                          New Value
--------------                          ---------
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-12:00       2011-10-01T16:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-11:00       2011-10-01T15:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-10:00       2011-10-01T14:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-09:00       2011-10-01T13:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-08:00       2011-10-01T12:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-07:00       2011-10-01T11:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-06:00       2011-10-01T10:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-05:00       2011-10-01T09:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-04:00       2011-10-01T08:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-03:00       2011-10-01T07:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-02:00       2011-10-01T06:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000-01:00       2011-10-01T05:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+00:00       2011-10-01T04:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+01:00       2011-10-01T03:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+02:00       2011-10-01T02:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+03:00       2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+04:00       2011-10-01T00:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+05:00       2011-09-30T23:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+06:00       2011-09-30T22:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+07:00       2011-09-30T21:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+08:00       2011-09-30T20:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+09:00       2011-09-30T19:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+10:00       2011-09-30T18:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+11:00       2011-09-30T17:18:54.6652000+03:00
2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652000+12:00       2011-09-30T16:18:54.6652000+03:00
```

How is it possible when converting to and then from it results with different string?

Is there a way to make it output the original string in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: What would you expect?  You have different `DateTime` instances in different timezones.  The goal of using those methods is to have a single timezone so they are consistent.  You'll need to keep track of the timezone if you want to be able to get back times for it.

Comment: I expect `ToString()` to create exactly the same string the instance of `DateTime` created from (by `ToDateTime()`). The goal of using those methods is to convert to and from xml dateTime format, and not modifying/calculating timezones, just use exactly the same timezone that in the `DateTime` instance.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. You are using obsolete methods that give you no control over how the time zone is interpreted.

Answer (score 5):

First, the [`XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shd19e3h.aspx) overload is **obsolete**. The documentation clearly specifies that you should use [`XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162342.aspx) instead. With it, you get to specify the [`XmlDateTimeSerializationMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatetimeserializationmode.aspx), which is documented as follows:

> One of the XmlDateTimeSerializationMode values that specify whether the date should be converted to local time or preserved as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), if it is a UTC date.

When you have an instance of `DateTime`, how it was constructed (its timezone, for instance) will be lost. The timezone will be properly parsed from the original string and converted to either UTC or local time, but what it was converted from is lost in the process.

If you want to preserve the timezone offset, use the [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) class. It behaves like `DateTime`, but preserves the timezone offset from which it was created. `XmlConvert` has a [`ToDateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todatetimeoffset.aspx) method that does exactly what you want. Here's a working example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,33}\t{1,33}", "Original Value", "New Value");
Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{0}", new String('-', 33));

for (int i = -12; i <= 12; i++)
{
    string sign = i < 0 ? "" : "+";
    string originalString = String.Format(
        "2011-10-01T01:18:54.6652123{0}{1:D2}:00", sign, i);
    DateTimeOffset dateTime = XmlConvert.ToDateTimeOffset(originalString);
    string newString = XmlConvert.ToString(dateTime);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", originalString, newString);
}
```

The only issue you have now is that `+00:00` will be serialized to `Z`, which can be avoided if you format the `newString` yourself, like so:

```
string newString = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz}", dateTime);
```

Comment: I tried all other overloads, and there is no overload that solving the issue of different output strings.

Comment: @DxCK, I've added a working example using the `DateTimeOffset` class which preserves the original timezone offset. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

What about [XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162344.aspx),
and to preserve the timezone offset use the parametre :

System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind

Comment: I tried all other overloads, and there is no overload that solving the issue of different output strings.