# Convert yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssz to date time - hour comes back incorrect

Tags: c#, date

I have a string in the following format:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

Example string:

```
2013-09-15T00:24:26.4215967Z
```

I need to convert this in to a date time, so I use the following code:

```
string testDateExample = "2013-09-15T00:24:26.4215967Z";
DateTime dateConversion = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(testDateExample);
Console.WriteLine(dateConversion);
```

Which will output:

```
9/15/2013 10:24:26 AM
```

Why is the 00 in the time being converted to 10 am?

Comment: note: it should be `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ` `MM` is for months, `mm` for minutes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787666/xmlconvert-todatetimestring-and-xmlconvert-tostringdatetime-outputs-are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is the 00 in the time being converted to 10 am?

`XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string)` returns a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Local` - in other words, it's converting the UTC value to the equivalent system local time. Presumably you're in a time zone which is in UTC+10 at the moment.

You'd be better off using `XmlConvert.ToDateTimeOffset`, or using the [overload which also takes an `XmlDateTimeSerializationMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162342.aspx):

```
string testDateExample = "2013-09-15T00:24:26.4215967Z";
DateTime dateConversion = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(testDateExample,
                                              XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
Console.WriteLine(dateConversion);
```

Note that you should already have received a warning about the overload you're currently using, as it's deprecated. I received this warning when compiling your code:

```
Test.cs(12,35): warning CS0618: 'System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string)' is
        obsolete: 'Use XmlConvert.ToDateTime() that takes in
        XmlDateTimeSerializationMode'
```

Always pay attention to warnings like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx)

```
string testDateExample = "2013-09-15T00:24:26.4215967Z";
DateTime dateConversion = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(testDateExample);
Console.WriteLine(dateConversion.ToUniversalTime());
```

for example in below code I'm getting two different results :

```
Console.WriteLine(dateConversion.ToUniversalTime()+"\n"+
                dateConversion);
```

Result :

```
09/15/2013 12:24:26 AM
09/15/2013 03:54:26 AM
```

Or as Jon said you can use [XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatetimeserializationmode.aspx):

```
string testDateExample = "2013-09-15T00:24:26.4215967Z";
DateTime dateConversion = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(testDateExample,XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
Console.WriteLine(dateConversion);
```